# JPanel is added onto other Jpanel on togglebutton Click

Tags: java, swing, popup, jbutton, jdialog

I am trying to make a popup panel which is activated with the help of JToggleButton.
I want the JPanel to be added onto the other Jpanel when ToggleButton is selected and hides when the ToggleButton is deselected.

I have declared the JToggleButton and used ItemListener. But What is happening is when i select the ToggleButton a panel is created if i deselect and Select it again another JPanel is added again and so on and After 5 clicks , Nothing appears.

```
public static JPanel createDesignButtons(){
    designButtonsPanel.setOpaque(false);
    BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(designButtonsPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
    designButtonsPanel.setLayout(boxLayout);

    mainButton.setIcon(Icons.venueIcon);
    mainButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    mainButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));
    mainButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
        if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        designButtonsPanel.add(createButtonsDialog());
        designButtonsPanel.validate();
        } else if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
        System.out.println("button is not selected");
        }
    }
});
    designButtonsPanel.add(mainButton);

    JLabel padding = new JLabel(" ");
    padding.setPreferredSize(null);

    JLabel divider = new JLabel("", Icons.dividerIcon, JLabel.CENTER);
    divider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3,45));
    designButtonsPanel.add(divider);


    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(designButtonsPanel);
    return(designButtonsPanel);
}
```

The above code is showing the mainButton is togglebutton that i want action on and the DesignButtonPanel is the Panel which is parent.

```
public static JPanel createButtonsDialog(){

    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonsPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.gray,1));
    return buttonsPanel;
}
```

This class show the panel i would like to add onto parent panel

How can i get the Panel added only once when the JtoggleButton is Selected and hides when its Deselected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you keep creating instances of your `JPanel`.
You could `remove` the `JPanel` if your `JToggleButton` is not selected and add an already created instance of your `JPanel` if the button is selected.
See this simple example:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
private JToggleButton toggleButton = new JToggleButton("Toggle");

public MainFrame() {
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    this.topPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    this.centerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    this.toggleButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

    this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(toggleButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.toggleButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            } else {
                remove(centerPanel);
            }
            pack();
        }
    });

    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

You can see that `centerPanel` is only instantiated once.